# Is there a way do color specific dates in input, type = "date"

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I would like to implement reservations. Because of that, some date ranges are already reserved. Is there any way to color specific dates in the pop up that comes out when I click the little calendar icon.
I would like to achieve something like this
[picture of calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfqn9.jpg)
where the red dates are already reserved
I'm open for any kind of implementation

Comment: Not possible, it is a simple date picker. Search online for 'html custom datepicker' for more sophisticated solutions.